# JDBC query formation

Tags: java, jdbc

I have table "A" in Oracle and I have same table in SQL server, but the problem is that the column names in oracle are all capital and those of sqlserver are in camel case, So right now while doing JDBC from java, I have to write different queries for oracle and sql server 
for eg.

```
select NAME.ADDRESS,ID from A  ---this is for oracle 
select Name.Address,Id from A  ---this is for sqlserver
```

so is there any way i can write a single query that would execute in both databases while using it in jdbc ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually verified that the database(s) are case sensitive? Neither is by default.

Comment: yes i have checked and found that they are case sensitive ,but i don't have permission to make them case insensitive!! :

Comment: Then write the queries for sqlserver; and call toUpperCase() on the query before calling Oracle.

Comment: Curious to know how you checked if Oracle and SQL Server are case sensitive.

Comment: hmm...thanx that could be one of the solution ....but if we consider things like select top 1 * from A and select * from A where rownum<2 we will have to write different queries for both db(s) and i am firing those queries based on driverclass mentioned in my dbcon.properties file....is that ok...?

Comment: @Nishan i fired queries on both db(s) and found that select NAME.ADDRESS,ID from A  ---doesnt work for SQL server  
select Name.Address,Id from A  ---doesnt work for oracle it gives me invalid column name error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the solution given by @Elliott Frisch. This will be good or else you can use [Unity JDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/). It automatically translate your query to the proper SQL dialect.

Hope this might help you

Thanks